# Embedding a page layout into a VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can we have a pagelayout of an object embedded into a Vf page?
I have a Vf page which has captures some information, i also want to be able to create a new event in the same page.

I could have all the event fields in the Vfpage and create the event. Is there a simpler way of doing it like embedding the events page layout into the VF page.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can just use the apex:detail tag.  See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_detail.htm

apex:detail uses the default page layout for the profile of the user viewing the page as well as the record type of the record being viewed.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:detail/>
  Put the rest of your page content here...
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [apex:iframe](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_iframe.htm) to embed content into a visualforce page

eg :

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:outputText value="The Account Is  "/>
  <apex:iframe src="/{!Account.Id}"   />
</apex:page>
```